# How to bootstrap component using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm running into an issue where my React components are just not being bootstrapped into the page, but no error messages are showing up so I don't know what's going on. I don't believe that the issue is with the CalcList.js or Calculator.js files, since I've been able to render them without any issue in a single-page (i.e. not using react-router) context.

Implemented using the index.js and App.js parents below, when I visit I just get an empty page without any feedback from the console.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import {Calculator} from './Calculator';
import {CalcList} from './CalcList';

render ((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={CalcList} />
        <Route path="/calculator/:num" component={Calculator} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import CalcList from './CalcList';
import Calculator from './Calculator';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
        return React.cloneElement(child);
    });
    return (
        <div id="app">
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you serving your app page (e.g. webpack dev server, other)? I ask because since you're using the HTML5 history api your server needs to support it (i.e.. when you request /calculator/1 your server should serve you index.html page). Does it work if inside index.js you do ```<Router history={hashHistory}>``` instead?

Comment: Also, why are you cloning App children instead of just doing ```return (
        <div id="app">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your already defining the default export in your components so the following lines are incorrect in index.js:

```
import {Calculator} from './Calculator';
import {CalcList} from './CalcList';
```

change to this:

```
import Calculator from './Calculator';
import CalcList from './CalcList';
```

Alternatively, You could create an object that exports those components like this:

components.js:

```
import Calculator from './Calculator';
import CalcList from './CalcList';

export {
    Calculator, 
    CalcList
}
```

and then your original imports would work like this:

```
import { Calculator, CalcList } from './components';
```